# Call the right overload from inside Generic function

Tags: c#, generics, overloading

I have following code, where i am trying to reach right overloaded function from inside generic function :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rextester
{
    class A 
    {
        public void a(int a) { Console.WriteLine("a: int"); }
        public void a(string a) { Console.WriteLine("a: string"); }
        public void a(int a, int b) { Console.WriteLine("a: int int"); }
        public void a(string a, string b) { Console.WriteLine("a: string string"); }
        public void a(params object[] args) { Console.WriteLine("a: object"); }
    }

    class B
    {
        A a;
        public B(A _a) { this.a = _a; }
        public void b1<T>(T t) { a.a(t); } 
        public void b2<T1, T2>(T1 t1, T2 t2) { a.a(t1, t2); }
        public void b(int i) { Console.WriteLine("b: int "); b1(i); }
        public void b(string i) { Console.WriteLine("b: string"); b1(i); }
        public void b(int i, int b) { Console.WriteLine("b : int int"); b2(i,b);}
        public void b(string i, string b) { Console.WriteLine("b: string string"); b2(i,b); }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Your code goes here
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!");
            B b = new B(new A());
            b.b(1);
            b.b("1");
            b.b(1,2);
            b.b("1", "2");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Hello, world!
b: int 
a: object
b: string
a: object
b : int int
a: object
b: string string
a: object
```

Expected output :

```
Hello, world!
b: int 
a: int
b: string
a: string
b : int int
a: int int
b: string string
a: string string
```

In case arguments don't match `public void a(params object[] args)` should be called.

For real world use, `A` is [EventSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracing.eventsource_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) and `a` is `WriteEvent`.
`B` is a codebase with many (~1000) `b`s with complicated argument(s) orders.
I can change `b1` and `b2` .. `bn` (n ~ 10) so as to make job easy.

Arguments for `a` are only native types like `int, string, long` Or `Guid`.

What can i do to achieve it ?
I am open to any other nice way to achieve the solution.

Comment: in my codebase .. `B inherits A `..
But does that make life easier ?

Comment: `a.a(t)` can only ever resolve to `a(params object[] args)`, because it's the only signature that matches the call for `T`. Overload resolution is not "redone" for every possible invocation of a generic method -- generics are not templates.

Comment: Is there any other way i can do this (easily) ?

Comment: One QQ, `b1(a);` takes the `int a` variable or `A a` variable? If it always takes object of `A`, then you must be always calling default method. What happens if you rename `int a` to say `int i`?

Comment: @AshishNegi: extract an interface and program against that and/or use `dynamic`,  proxies (Castle DynamicProxy and the like), code rewriting (PostSharp and the like), T4 template generation, or just roll your own code to do one-time code generation by reflecting over the methods you want to intercept/wrap. None of this is terribly easy, but will certainly beat manual labor.

Comment: @praty tried your doubt.. still same issue.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Can you just answer this with the different pros and cons.. EventSourcing is a heavy runtime resource operation.. That is why i want to avoid `params object[]` call.

Comment: @AshishNegi: I lack the time to do so. I hope someone else will pick up the slack. I have little experience with tracing; I just use `log4net` in contexts where I don't need to bother about performance (and if there is, I can just turn it off). There's almost certainly *some* solution that would be perfect in this case, but I don't know which one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the overload resolution for calls from generic methods still happens at compile time, so unless there are generic type constraints, the generic type is considered to be `object` for most things inside the function.

If you want a different behavior, you need a runtime overload resolution. One way to archieve it is to use the `dynamic` type for the method calls that should use some overloads:

```
public void b1<T>(T t) { a.a((dynamic)t); }
public void b2<T1, T2>(T1 t1, T2 t2) { a.a((dynamic)t1, (dynamic)t2); }
```

However, this will basically ignore the generic type:

Suppose you write

```
public void b(int i) { Console.WriteLine("b: int "); b1<object>(i); }
```

Then the dynamic will ignore your explicitely given `object` type and still call the `int` overload of `a.a`

Another way would be reflection, inspecting the generic type and trying to call matching method overloads.